# нужна помощь в редактировании скрипта

Tags: jquery

```
немного запутался в скрипте
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function setupLabel() {
    //checkbox
    if ($('.fake-checkbox-label input').length) {

      $('.fake-checkbox-label label').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
      });

      $('.fake-checkbox-label input:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).prev('label').addClass('checked');
      });
    }

    //radio buttons
    if ($('.fake-radio-label input').length) {

      $('.fake-radio-label label').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
      });

      $('.fake-radio-label input:checked').each(function() {
        $(this).prev("label").addClass('checked');
      });
    }
  }

  $('input.hidden-input').css({'position':'absolute', 'left':'-9999px'});

  $('.fake-checkbox-label, .fake-radio-label').click(function() {
    //console.log($(this).find("input"));
    //$(this).find("input").attr("checked", true);
    setupLabel();
  });
  setupLabel();

});
```

и есть html блоки

```html
<div class="tab-block">
  <div class="checkbox">
      <div class = "fake-radio-label">
        <label for="radio_1"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="hidden-input" name="radio" id="radio_1" form="main_form">        
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Описание товара 1</div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/master-card.png" height="17" width="28" alt=""><span>Информация о карте</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="tab-block">
  <div class="checkbox">
      <div class = "fake-radio-label">
        <label for="radio_2"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="hidden-input" name="radio" id="radio_2" form="main_form">        
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Описание товара 2</div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="img/master-card.png" height="17" width="28" alt=""><span>Информация о карте</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

как сделать так чтобы при клике по div class="tab-block" срабатывал checkbox именно в этом блоке, и при клике на 2-й срабатывал на 2-ом?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tab-block').on('click',function(){
   $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked') ? false : true ); 
});
```